SwiftUI Stacked sheets
I am having a big app, that using a lot of sheets in SwiftUI. All works fine till I need to have some automatic sheets that can pop up anytime with some trigger that the user didn't do themselves.
Then .sheet modifier would not allow two sheets to come over each other. Unless I injected this sheets under every sheet in the app. which is cumbersome.
For example
var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundStyle(.tint)
            Text("Hello, world!")
        }
        .onTapGesture {
            sheet1Open.toggle()
        }
.sheet(isPresented: $sheet1Open) {
  Sheet1Veiw() 
        .onTapGesture {
            sheet2Open.toggle()
        }
}
.sheet(isPresented: $sheet2Open) {
  Sheet2Veiw() 
}

would never works.. while if i nested the second .sheet under the Sheet1View. It would work of course.
I am open to any suggestions, I tried to have a sheet manager that juggle between the automated sheets but it is buggy and cumbersome as well.

You cannot display two sheets at the same time.
Note that displaying a sheet within another sheet is not a great idea.
You will need to construct your own system using some View and maybe a ZStack and some animation as well.

How about writing your own sheet modifier that does what the built-in sheet modifier does, but also nests the additional sheet inside?

@Sweeper am open to that . the sheet manager was kind of that . but not scalable and imperative specific for specific screens that keep show and hide based on what shown. not great. any declarative idea would be great

While technically it may be possible, the bigger question is why do you need to do this? Why should a tap on (the entire) Sheet1View open a sheet in the view it's called from? Can't it open its own sheet?

Technically, it is possible to stack sheets, by opening a sheet and then opening another sheet defined in the view presented in the first sheet - see Method 2 below.
I was going to put together an example showing a couple of methods, but it turned out to be more exhaustive (and complete). See full code at the end.

Here are some notes on the different methods shown.
Method 1 - Navigate to another view in the same sheet
Before considering stacking sheets, it's worth considering if it would be more appropriate to simply navigate to another view within the same sheet. This can be done by wrapping the view presented in the sheet in a NavigationStack, and using a NavigationLink in the presented view to show other views without opening additional sheets.
So in the main view:
.sheet(isPresented: $openSheet) {
    NavigationStack {
        PrimaryView()
    }
    .presentationDetents([.medium])
}

And then in the presented view:
//Method 1 - Navigate to another view in the same sheet
VStack {
    Text("Method 1:")
        .foregroundStyle(.black)
    NavigationLink("Navigate to Secondary View") {
                    SecondaryView()
    }
}

Method 2 - Open Secondary View in a sheet of Primary View
Possibly the simplest way to stack sheets is to open a sheet from within the view already presented in the sheet.
So main view would have the main sheet showing PrimaryView:
.sheet(isPresented: $openSheet) {
        PrimaryView()
    .presentationDetents([.medium])
}

And then PrimaryView would have its own sheet configured to show SecondaryView:
.sheet(isPresented: $openSomeSheet){
    SecondaryView()
        .presentationDetents([.medium])
}

This would have the effect of opening a sheet on top of an already open sheet, without closing the initial sheet, effectively stacking them.
If the secondary view had its sheet modifier, the stacking of sheets could continue.
Method 3 - Open Secondary View in another sheet of the main view
If the main view has multiple sheets defined and you open one (presenting PrimaryView) and then want to open a second sheet (that is defined in the main view) from within PrimaryView, it is possible if you pass a binding to the second sheet trigger to PrimaryView.
So main view would have triggers for the various sheets:
@State private var openSheet: Bool = false
@State private var openAnotherSheet: Bool = false

And it would pass a binding to the second sheet trigger (openAnotherSheet) to PrimaryView:
.sheet(isPresented: $openSheet) {
    NavigationStack {
        PrimaryView(openAnotherSheet: $openAnotherSheet)
    }
    .presentationDetents([.medium])
}
.sheet(isPresented: $openAnotherSheet) {
    SecondaryView()
}

Then, PrimaryView would receive the binding parameter:
struct PrimaryView: View {
    
    var openAnotherSheet: Binding<Bool>
    //...

Which allows toggling the trigger to open the other sheet in the main view:
Button {
    dismiss()
    openAnotherSheet.wrappedValue.toggle()
} label: {
    Text("Close and Open Secondary View")
}

Note, however, that in order for the second sheet to actually show, the initial sheet must be dismissed, achieved here using the environment dismiss action.
Method 4 - Close and Open any view dynamically
The methods so far are fairly simple, but can become less practical as the number of sheets increases, or when there is a need for dynamic opening of sheets, especially if they need to be triggered from views that may not be setup with special bindings to the main view's sheet triggers.
In this case, a more dynamic approach is to not have to define multiple sheets in the main view, using instead a single sheet that will automatically show whatever view is specified in an observable object.
So main view would have:
.sheet(item: $sheetNavigator.exampleSheet) { sheet in
    sheet.view
}

Where exampleSheet is a property of an @Observable singleton class SheetNavigator:
@Observable
class SheetNavigator {
    static let nav = SheetNavigator()
    
    var sheet: SheetRoute?
    var exampleSheet: SheetRoute? // for demonstrating Method 4 only
    
    private init() {}
}

And where exampleSheet's type is an enum that defines the various "routes" of views that can be shown in sheets:
enum SheetRoute: Identifiable {
    case primary, secondary, tertiary, optional
    
    //conform to Identifiable
    var id: SheetRoute { self }
    
    @ViewBuilder
    var view: some View {
        switch self {
            case .primary: PrimaryView()
            case .secondary: SecondaryView()
            case .tertiary: TertiaryView()
            case .optional: OptionalView()
        }
    }
}

With this setup, the PrimaryView shown in the presented sheet (or any view for that matter) can open the main view's sheet by setting the singleton's sheet property to the view that should be presented in the sheet:
Button {
    dismiss()
    SheetNavigator.nav.exampleSheet = .tertiary // try .secondary here also
} label: {
    Text("Open Tertiary View dynamically")
}

Note that here also any open sheets must be dismissed for any other sheets to show.
Method 5 - Open any view magically
While Method 4's dynamic way can be useful, it still doesn't allow actual stacking of sheets, since as shown in previous examples, stacking would require for each view to define its own sheet modifier.
Even then, there could be issues due to the fact that all sheets would observe a shared property, which could cause a cascading effect of sheets opening and closing multiple times. This can be remedied by adding necessary logic to prevent it, but then this logic would have to be added everywhere a "dynamic" sheet modifier exists, which wouldn't be viable.
Thus, the need for a view modifier that defines the sheet management and observing logic centrally and also adds the sheet modifier via a view extension, referred to here as the .sheetMagician() modifier.
//Add sheet opening support to any view using the associated view extension modifier .sheetMagician()
struct SheetMagicianModifier: ViewModifier {
    
    //State values
    @State private var selectedSheet: SheetRoute?
    @State private var showSheet: Bool = false
    @State private var viewAppeared: Bool = false
    
    //Modifier body
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .onChange(of: SheetNavigator.nav.sheet) { oldValue, newValue in
                
                if selectedSheet == nil {
                    selectedSheet = newValue
                }
                //if the view never appeared, it was probably opened in another sheet
                else if selectedSheet != nil, viewAppeared == false {
                    //reset current states to ensure a sheet won't open upon dismissal of other sheets
                    selectedSheet = nil
                    showSheet = false
                }
            }
            .onChange(of: selectedSheet) {
                if selectedSheet != nil {
                    showSheet = true
                }
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet, onDismiss: {
                selectedSheet = nil
                SheetNavigator.nav.sheet = nil
            }) {
                selectedSheet?.view
                    .onAppear {
                        viewAppeared = true
                    }
                    .onDisappear {
                        viewAppeared = false
                    }
                    .presentationDetents([.medium])
            }
    }
}

This "magical" modifier has its own states to manage the sheet display logic based on the changes of the singleton's values. It can be added to any view that needs to support opening sheets that are opened by setting the SheetNavigator sheet property.
If you run the code and click around, you will notice that view that don't have specific .sheet modifiers can open sheets in a stacking manner and those that do already have other .sheet modifiers defined also (should) work.
Here's the full code:

import SwiftUI

struct StackedSheets: View {
    
    //State values
    @State private var openSheet: Bool = false
    @State private var openAnotherSheet: Bool = false
    @Bindable var sheetNavigator = SheetNavigator.nav
    
    //Body
    var body: some View {
        
        Button {
            openSheet.toggle()
        } label: {
            VStack(spacing: 5) {
                Image(systemName: "globe")
                    .imageScale(.large)
                Text("Open sheet")
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $openSheet) {
            NavigationStack {
                PrimaryView(openAnotherSheet: $openAnotherSheet)
            }
            .presentationDetents([.medium])
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $openAnotherSheet) {
            SecondaryView()
        }
        .sheet(item: $sheetNavigator.exampleSheet) { sheet in
            sheet.view
        }
    }
}

struct PrimaryView: View {
    
    //Parameters
    var openAnotherSheet: Binding<Bool>
    
    //Initializer that sets openAnotherSheet to false if not provided as a parameter
    init(openAnotherSheet: Binding<Bool> = .constant(false)) {
        self.openAnotherSheet = openAnotherSheet
    }
    
    //Environment values
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss

    //State values
    @State private var openSomeSheet = false
    
    //Body
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(spacing: 15) {
            Text("Sheet 1 View")
                .font(.title)
            
            //Method 1 - Navigate to another view in the same sheet
            VStack {
                Text("Method 1:")
                    .foregroundStyle(.black)
                NavigationLink("Navigate to Secondary View") {
                    SecondaryView()
                }
            }
            
            //Method 2 - Open Secondary View in a sheet of Primary View
            VStack {
                Text("Method 2:")
                    .foregroundStyle(.black)
                Button {
                    openSomeSheet.toggle()
                } label: {
                    Text("Open Secondary View in sheet")
                }
            }
            
            //Method 3 - Open Secondary View in a sheet of StackedSheets view
            VStack {
                Text("Method 3:")
                    .foregroundStyle(.black)
                Button {
                    dismiss()
                    openAnotherSheet.wrappedValue.toggle()
                } label: {
                    Text("Close and Open Secondary View")
                }
            }
            
            //Method 4 - Close and Open any view dynamically
            VStack {
                Text("Method 4:")
                    .foregroundStyle(.black)
                Button {
                    dismiss()
                    SheetNavigator.nav.exampleSheet = .tertiary // try .secondary here also
                } label: {
                    Text("Open Tertiary View dynamically")
                }
            }
            
            //Method 5 - Open any view magically
            VStack {
                Text("Method 5:")
                    .foregroundStyle(.black)
                Button {
                    SheetNavigator.nav.sheet = .optional
                } label: {
                    Text("Open Optional View  magically")
                }
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $openSomeSheet){
            SecondaryView()
                .presentationDetents([.medium])
        }
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarLeading) {
                Button {
                    dismiss()
                } label: {
                    Text("Cancel")
                }
            }
        }
        
        //Support to open any sheet
        .sheetMagician()
        
    }
}

struct SecondaryView: View {
    
    //Environment values
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    
    //Body
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            
            //View title
            Text("Secondary View")
                .font(.title)
            
            //Open any sheet
            VStack {
                Text("Method 5:")
                    .foregroundStyle(.black)
                Button {
                    SheetNavigator.nav.sheet = .tertiary
                } label: {
                    Text("Open Tertiary View magically")
                }
            }
            .padding()
            
            //Close button
            Button {
                dismiss()
            } label: {
                Text("Close")
            }
            .padding()
        }
        
        //Support to open any sheet
        .sheetMagician()
    }
}

struct TertiaryView: View {
    
    //Environment values
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    
    //Body
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            
            //View title
            Text("Tertiary View")
                .font(.title)
            
            //Open any sheet
            Button {
                SheetNavigator.nav.sheet = .optional
            } label: {
                Text("Open Optional View magically")
            }
            .padding()
            
            //Close button
            Button {
                dismiss()
            } label: {
                Text("Close")
            }
            .padding()
        }
        .presentationDetents([.medium])
        
        //Support to open any sheet
        .sheetMagician()
    }
}

struct OptionalView: View {
    
    //Environment values
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    
    //Body
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            
            //View title
            Text("Optional View")
                .font(.title)
            
            //Open any sheet
            Button {
                SheetNavigator.nav.sheet = .tertiary
            } label: {
                Text("Open Tertiary View magically")
            }
            .padding()
            
            //Close button
            Button {
                dismiss()
            } label: {
                Text("Close")
            }
            .padding()
        }
        .presentationDetents([.medium])
        
        //Support to open any sheet
        .sheetMagician()

    }
}

//View extensions
extension View {
    
    //Functions that calls a ViewModifier to add sheet opening support to any view
    func sheetMagician() -> some View {
        self
            .modifier( SheetMagicianModifier() )
    }
}

//Add sheet opening support to any view using the associated view extension modifier .sheetMagician()
struct SheetMagicianModifier: ViewModifier {
    
    //State values
    @State private var selectedSheet: SheetRoute?
    @State private var showSheet: Bool = false
    @State private var viewAppeared: Bool = false
    
    //Modifier body
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .onChange(of: SheetNavigator.nav.sheet) { oldValue, newValue in
                
                if selectedSheet == nil {
                    selectedSheet = newValue
                }
                //if the view never appeared, it was probably opened in another sheet
                else if selectedSheet != nil, viewAppeared == false {
                    //reset current states to ensure a sheet won't open upon dismissal of other sheets
                    selectedSheet = nil
                    showSheet = false
                }
            }
            .onChange(of: selectedSheet) {
                if selectedSheet != nil {
                    showSheet = true
                }
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet, onDismiss: {
                selectedSheet = nil
                SheetNavigator.nav.sheet = nil
            }) {
                selectedSheet?.view
                    .onAppear {
                        viewAppeared = true
                    }
                    .onDisappear {
                        viewAppeared = false
                    }
                    .presentationDetents([.medium])
            }
    }
}

//Enum for defining possible routes for sheets (since sheet(item:_) requires conforming to Identifiable
enum SheetRoute: Identifiable {
    case primary, secondary, tertiary, optional
    
    //conform to Identifiable
    var id: SheetRoute { self }
    
    @ViewBuilder
    var view: some View {
        switch self {
            case .primary: PrimaryView()
            case .secondary: SecondaryView()
            case .tertiary: TertiaryView()
            case .optional: OptionalView()
        }
    }
}

//Observable singleton class
@Observable
class SheetNavigator {
    static let nav = SheetNavigator()
    
    var sheet: SheetRoute?
    var exampleSheet: SheetRoute? // for demonstrating Method 4 only
    
    private init() {}
}

//Preview
#Preview {
    StackedSheets()
}

